# ruby methods that either yield or return Enumerator

Tags: ruby, enumerable

in recent versions of Ruby, many methods in `Enumerable` return an `Enumerator` when they are called without a block:

```
[1,2,3,4].map 
#=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:map> 
[1,2,3,4].map { |x| x*2 }
#=> [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

I want do do the same thing in my own methods like so:

```
class Array
  def double(&block)
    # ???
  end
end

arr = [1,2,3,4]

puts "with block: yielding directly"
arr.double { |x| p x } 

puts "without block: returning Enumerator"
enum = arr.double
enum.each { |x| p x }
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The core libraries insert a guard `return to_enum(:name_of_this_method, arg1, arg2, ..., argn) unless block_given?`. In your case:

```
class Array
  def double
    return to_enum(:double) unless block_given?
    each { |x| yield 2*x }
  end
end

>> [1, 2, 3].double { |x| puts(x) }
2
4
6 
>> ys = [1, 2, 3].double.select { |x| x > 3 } 
#=> [4, 6]
```

Comment: neat. didn't know about this.

Comment: Small note:
Sometimes your function needs to accept parameters, so using `to_enum` with just the `:my_method` won't work (because when the enumerable will be enumerated, your function will be invoked without parameters).

For example if the example here was `def mult_by(factor) ... end` you would need to use `to_enum(:my_method, factor)`.

Answer (score 11):

use [Enumerator#new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-c-new):

```
class Array
  def double(&block)
    Enumerator.new do |y| 
      each do |x| 
        y.yield x*2 
      end 
    end.each(&block)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - the use of `.each(&block)` was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Another approach might be:

```
class Array
    def double(&block)
        map {|y| y*2 }.each(&block)
    end
 end
```

Comment: That's the essence of it, but in contrast to @levinalex' answer, this solution runs the map across the whole array before any consumer calls each.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way for me

```
class Array
  def iter
      @lam = lambda {|e| puts e*3}
      each &@lam
  end
end

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
array.iter
```

=>
3
6
9
12
15
18
21